# Is it possible to make more than one connection between two classes in class diagram?

Tags: uml, class-diagram

Exemplary situation. listing1 and listing2 has two different purposes and can't be combined into one list. Is it legal in UML to create two separate lines between A and B like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DJ1V.png).

```
class A {
    List<B> listing1;
    List<B> listing2;
    /* omitted */
}

class B {/* omitted */}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid case. Each relationship may have different multiplicity.

Comment: and each relationship should use different roles for the association ends to avoid ambiguities